# Conceptual inquiry about networking via python

Tags: python, networking, scapy

I have written a script in Python which searches for 802.11 Probe Requests from nearby computers, in order to obtain their preferred network names.

Previously I used nmap -sn to return available hosts on my 10.0.0.0/24 network, however a host I knew to be 'live' did not appear (.12), so I used nmap -sL instead.

When I run my script I am connected to AP X.

Q1) Why don't I receive the preferred network names from host .12? Could it be that a firewall is hiding information?

Q2) Why don't I receive preferred network names of other hosts belonging to AP Y, AP Z etc. which are visible from my computer?

- I have set monitoring mode on wlan0, so the interface being used is mon0. Doesn't that mean that hosts from other access points should register?

> ```
> #!/usr/bin/python
>
>         from scapy.all import *
>
>         probereq = []
>
>         def getprobe(pkt):
>           if pkt.haslayer(Dot11ProbeReq):
>               netname = pkt.getlayer(Dot11ProbeReq).info
>               if netname not in probereq:
>                   probereq.append(netname)
>                   print netname 
>
>         sniff(iface="mon0", prn=getprobe)
> ```

**NOTE**: This question may also be valid for networkengineering.stackexchange.com

Apologies in advance if the question is too basic.

Comment: Yes your question is about networking! You may move it there for better answers. Firewall could be the issue. Ping the `host .12` to see if it is alive. Beware some firewalls may even drop ping packets. If it is alive, then try running wireshark on the `host .12` and see if it is generating any traffic or not.

Comment: I cannot ping `.12`, and since it did not appear in `nmap -sn` I guess the firewall is dropping ICMP packets. Can I get any information about this host?

Comment: Try banner grabbing using telnet. Telnet to port 80 or 443. Try telnet to different ports like 25 SMTP etc. Its all about trying experimenting different things. Try this http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg144582.aspx

Comment: @khadija, is the host `.12` connected to the same network via wifi? If so, I don't think it should send any probe requests packets. Have you tried switching `mon0`'s channels in the background?

Comment: pss, I am using Linux, but thanks
@Yoel yes it is. But if it was disconnected from the wifi, how would I find any information about it because it would not be 'up'?
No I haven't.

Comment: You are sniffing probe request packets. I don't think a machine already connected to an AP sends any such packets as it is not looking for an AP to connect to. This doesn't explain why you can't ping that machine, as it should reply if you're both connected to the same network but maybe that's a firewall issue. Lastly, I think it would be better to actively switch channels on the sniffing host, although to the best of my understanding, probe request packets should be sent across all channels.